# ufw deny from IP ADDRESS still allows http access to website

Tags: ufw

I just typed these commands into bash on my ubuntu server

```
ufw deny from 173.244.48.185
ufw reload
ufw status
```

And this gave this result

```
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    97.107.131.16
[ 2] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    123.111.111.111
[ 3] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
... alot of other records
[30] Anywhere                   DENY IN     173.244.48.185
[31] 80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[32] 443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I went to google and typed `my ip` to confirm that my IP address is indeed 173.244.48.185.

I then typed the address of my webserver I can still see my website.  I also see on the apache server that `access.log` recorded my access.

How do I get UFW to reject all access to my server?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @John rule [31] and [32] are for ipv6. You are specifying ipv4 addresses. Rules [3] and [4] are likely culprits.

Comment: @Ivan when i remove rules 3 and 4, then no one can access the website.  When I remove rules 31 and 32, it doesn't seem to have any effect on anyone's access to the server.  Any other suggestions on how to allow everyone except 173.244.48.185?  I can' tseem to figure out the syntax of the command that will do what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the matches are sequential, and you are connecting to either port 80 or 443, so the rules [3] and [4] permit access ignoring any subsequent rules.

Maybe something like

```
ufw insert 3 deny from 173.244.48.185
```